# Facebook InsightsAPI calls limited to 25 entries

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm currently trying to use the InsightsAPI of Facebook in order to extract our performance data. The problem is that the response of the API call is limited to 25 entries.

I use the following code for the call:

```
String access_token = "xxx";
String ad_account_id = "yyy";
setApp_secret("zzz");

APIContext context = new APIContext(access_token).enableDebug(false);
APINodeList<AdsInsights> response = new AdAccount(ad_account_id,   context).getInsights()
  .setLevel(AdsInsights.EnumLevel.VALUE_CAMPAIGN)
.setBreakdowns(Arrays.asList(AdsInsights.EnumBreakdowns.VALUE_COUNTRY))
  .setTimeRange("{\"since\":\"2017-09-01\",\"until\":\"2017-09-30\"}")
 .requestField("account_id")
 .requestField("campaign_id")
 .requestField("impressions")
 .requestField("clicks")
  .execute();
```

How can I extend the limit of the response? I found some information about how to do this via curl but there were no hints on how to do this with java. Would be great if anyone of you could help me!

All the best,
Paul

Comment: _"but there were no hints on how to do this with java"_ - there is a pretty obvious hint right there in the SDK's readme file, https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-ads-sdk#read _"** Important **: Handling pagination: Most edge APIs have default pagination, which returns a limited number of objects (~30 objects) instead of the entire list. If you want to load more, you need to make a separate API call. In our SDK, you can call to nextPage() get next page"_

Comment: Thanks! That helped my a lot. Somehow I skipped this information!

Answer (score 2):

All the responses of Graph API are paginated which means you will get at most 'x' number of results where 'x' is 25 by default at the moment.

You can specify a higher value using `limit` param but it is not recommended as it is likely to cause a timeout.

You should look into using pagination instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging